# excel vba check for Hebrew in text entered, using keypress keyascii

Tags: excel, vba, keypress, hebrew, extended-ascii

In my Excel-2013 VBA project I have a UserForm with a textbox. I need this textbox to accept only digits, A-Z, a-z, and the 27 Hebrew letters.

```
Private Sub my_TextBox_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    If (Not (KeyAscii > 47 And KeyAscii < 58))  And _          <= 0-9
       (Not (KeyAscii > 64 And KeyAscii < 91))  And _          <= A-Z
       (Not (KeyAscii > 96 And KeyAscii < 123)) And _          <= a-z
       (Not (KeyAscii > 127 And KeyAscii < 155)) Then          <= Hebrew
          KeyAscii = 8
          Beep
    End If
End Sub
```

Works fine except for the Hebrew.
It does not recognize ASCII 128 thru 154 as Hebrew (These values are found in ASCII code page 862).
That is, trying to type Hebrew letters in the textbox results in a beep.
How do I tell Excel to use ASCII code page 862?

Comment: try changing the font or check what the KeyAscii numbers are

Comment: have you tried `Debug.Print KeyAscii`? it should tell you what have been used...

Comment: @ Dirk Reichel - Thank you very much, Dirk. (Should have thought of it myself...).  Seems like **the Hebrew alphabet in ASCII is between 1488 and 1514**. Works fine now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dirk Reichel gave me the simple idea of debugging and checking what goes into my_TextBox when entering a Hebrew character in it.
That's how I found that **the Hebrew alphabet in ASCII is between 1488 and 1514**.
My code now is :

```
Private Sub my_TextBox_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
   If (Not (KeyAscii > 47 And KeyAscii < 58))  And _          <= 0-9
      (Not (KeyAscii > 64 And KeyAscii < 91))  And _          <= A-Z
      (Not (KeyAscii > 96 And KeyAscii < 123)) And _          <= a-z
      (Not (KeyAscii > 1487 And KeyAscii < 1515)) Then        <= Hebrew
         KeyAscii = 8
         Beep
   End If
End Sub
```

Now it allows for Hebrew too.
Thank you Dirk.